# Match rows between dataframes, and take the mean of all that match

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have about 90 dataframes, each of which are about 1 Gb and have ~5 million rows.

In each of the 90 there is a unique ID that matches all the other dataframes.

An example of two of these are

df1

```
Year ID Value
1950 1  0.4
1950 2  0.2
1950 3  0.1
1950 4  0.8
```

df2

```
Year ID Value
1951 1  0.9
1951 2  0.6
1951 3  0.7
1951 4  0.6
```

I want to take the mean across all frames where the `ID` matches. Since each individual file is so large I cant hold them all in memory.  I have come up with an approach but it is incredibly slow and I am hoping for a better way.

The current approach is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

#list with unique ids found in all frames
uniques = np.arange(1,5000000, 1)

#loop through files
files = "C:/path_to_csvs"

#empty dataframe to store all means
final = pd.DataFrame()

for i in uniques:

    #empty dataframe to append a single matching unique ID
    single_combined = pd.DataFrame()

    for f in os.listdir(files):

        df2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(files, f))     

        #select rows where the id's match
        df2 = df2[(df2['ID'] == i)]

        #if there is a match, append the row
        if df2.shape[0] != 0:

             single_combined =  single_combined.append(df2)

    #groupby ID to get the means of value
    means = single_combined.groupby(['ID'])[['Value]].mean().reset_index()

    #append the mean to the final dataframe
    final = final.append(means)

print(final)
```

Comment: Why read all columns in `read_csv` when you're working on 2-3 columns?

Comment: The real data has 50 columns, and the only one not needed is `Year`.  I supposed I could drop that but I'm not sure that will result in large efficiency gains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea**: `mean` = `sum` / `count`, so let's read all files one=by-one, calculate `sum` and `count` (`size`) for each of them, and sum it up, storing cumulative `sum` and `count`. When we are done with all files we can easily calculate `mean` = `sum` / `count`.

So consider the following approach:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('d:/temp/.data/46307213/*.csv')

res = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    res = pd.concat([res,
                     pd.read_csv(f).groupby('ID')['Value']
                       .agg(['sum', 'size'])]) \
            .groupby('ID').sum()

res['mean'] = res.pop('sum') / res.pop('size')
```

Demo:

Source CSV files:

1.csv:

```
Year,ID,Value
1950,1,0.4
1950,2,0.2
1950,3,0.1
1950,4,0.8
```

2.csv:

```
Year,ID,Value
1951,1,0.9
1951,2,0.6
1951,5,0.7
1951,6,0.6
```

3.csv:

```
Year,ID,Value
1952,1,0.9
1952,1,0.6
1952,5,0.7
1952,5,0.6
```

Result:

```
In [103]: %paste
import glob

files = glob.glob('d:/temp/.data/46307213/*.csv')
res = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    res = pd.concat([res,
                     pd.read_csv(f).groupby('ID')['Value']
                       .agg(['sum', 'size'])]) \
            .groupby('ID').sum()
res['mean'] = res.pop('sum') / res.pop('size')
print(res)

## -- End pasted text --
        mean
ID
1   0.700000
2   0.400000
3   0.100000
4   0.800000
5   0.666667
6   0.600000
```

**Conclusion:** each file will be read up from disk only once.

Comment: It will take me a bit to actually test on the data, but I see no reason why this should't be better.

Comment: This algorithm has complexity `O(#_of_files)`, compared to `O(#_of_unique_vals * #_of_files)`

Comment: do you know why this line, `res['mean'] = res.pop('sum') / res.pop('size')` returns `KeyError: 'sum'`?

Comment: ahhh I see, I think its because I have 50 columns I aggregated and not one, I therefore have 50 `sum` columns and 50 `size` columns